# How to prove that the product of two matrix sums is commutative.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to prove the following statement:

> If $S$ is a real, antisymmetric matrix then $A=(I-S)(I+S)^{-1}$ is orthogonal.

The first part of the proof is fairly simple:

$$
A^T=[(I+S)^{-1}]^T(1-S)^T=[(I+S)^T]^{-1}(1-S)^T=[(I+S)^T]^{-1}(1-S)^T=(I^T+S^T)^{-1}(I^T-S^T)=(I-S)^{-1}(I+S)
$$

$$A^{^-1}=(I+S)(I-S)^{-1}$$

For $A$ to be orthogonal, $A^{-1}=A^T$. However, this means that the two matrices $(I+S)$ and $(I-S)^{-1}$ must be commutative. How do I prove this?

Answer (score 2):

$(I+S)(I-S)=(I-S)(I+S)$. Multiply on the left by $(I-S)^{-1}$ and on the right also by $(I-S)^{-1}$.

Proof of invertibility of $I-S$: $\langle Sx, y \rangle=-\langle x, Sy \rangle$ for al $x,y$ because $S$ is real and anti-symmetric. Hence $(I-S)x=0$ implies $Sx=x$ which implies (taking $x=y$) $\langle x, x \rangle=-\langle x, x \rangle$. We get $\|x\|^{2}=-\|x\|^{2}$ or $\|x\|^{2}=0$. Thus $(I-S)x=0$ implies $x=0$, so $I-S$ is non-singular.

Comment: How do we know $I-S$ is invertible?

Comment: If $S$ is real and antisymmetric then $Sx=x$ implies $x=0$ so $I-S$ is invertible. Anyway, it is clear that OP already knows that.

Comment: Actually that didn't occur to me. Could you elucidate your reasoning a bit more please?

Comment: @Pancake_Senpai I have added a proof of invertibility of $I-S$.